# Exit handlers for Visual Studio Code debug enviroment

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode for developing and came to the point when I need to do something before the script stops. I added an exit handler on `exit` and `SIGUSR1`, but none of them actually trigger when I'm using the debug feature and pressing stop/restart there.

How can I do something when VSCode debugger stops/restarts the script? (Both JS and Python answers are acceptable).

I'm using `process.on()` in node.js and `signal.signal()` and `atexit` in Python.

Comment: Wanted the same, but from the last paragraph of Microsoft's [Node.js debugging in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_stop-debugging) page: "_Note that on the Windows operating system, pressing Stop always forcibly kills the debuggee and its child processes._" it looks like it just kills things stone-dead (at least under Windows).